# google-api-php-client-0.5.0 callbackurl?

Tags: php, api, google-api

I am new to integrating api and I am trying to working with the  `google-api-php-client-0.6.0` and I registered my app at Google and also configured them in `simple.php` in dev.siva.com virtual host

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/contacts/");
// Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=contacts to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
// $client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
// $client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
// $client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_redirect_uri');
// $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
  $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
  print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if (isset($auth)) {
    print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
    print "<a class=logout href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
```

I am able to login and I gave the redirect url to above code and I am being redirected but the problem is I am getting unable to connect page. Why?

The url is like this after redirection

```
    https://dev.siva.com/simple.php?code=4/hqJo9FDtjcn46uuP6JXE
DuWLKTQn.Eo91flf65bgaXE-sT2ZLcbRbNNSqdQI
```

Comment: I've had unknown issues in the past... Do you have the very latest svn update? http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/GettingStarted#Obtaining_the_most_up-to-date_version_from_SVN

Comment: i dont have any svn installed

Comment: Oke, then you could try that. Sometimes the released version is not the best and patches are submitted later via SVN. So I'd suggest you install an SVN client first then.

Comment: Since you made it to the redirect `simple.php` is probably set up correctly. The next thing the sample project does is run `$client->authenticate();` which makes a server side call to Google. If the client library is unable to complete this call, it may explain the problem. Two things you can try are: 1) check the server side http server log. You'll probably find a stack trace or error in it that explains the root cause. 2) Fire up a local http server on localhost. Does the code exhibit the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use virtual host as redirect uri - refer https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp for more details. So you have two options - process it on {http://localhost} or get the code in title bar instead of query parameter. I would choose the first.